# Reaching the maximum length of file uploaded

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an asp.net application of uploading files:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Uploading_validation", "Akeo", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="dossier" />
   <br />
 <input type="submit" value="OK" />
 }
```

when i select a compressede file to upload an exeption of `Maximum request length exceeded.` that indicated that the length of the file is higher than the maximum length.

How can i change the length of file to maximum ? and what is this maximum's value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx

Comment: where can i find this line in asp.net mvc application

Comment: web.config, if this specific line does not exist, you should add it.

Comment: plz see my file web.config http://pastebin.com/8WSyMbMh where can i put this line because i tried and didn't work :(

Comment: on 24th line change <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" /> to     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="3276800" />

Answer (score 1):

Read this
 http://forums.eukhost.com/f15/increase-file-upload-size-asp-asp-net-9378/#.UaX6F6KBmM4

also you can read from MSDN site about runtime